# CaptchaMvc.Mvc5 does not showing the refresh button?

Tags: asp.net-mvc

I want to create a Captcha to add new users on my website. To do this I'm trying to use the `CaptchaMvc.Mvc5` but it doesn't show de refresh button to change the captcha image.

Looking at the developer inspect of Chrome it has an exception about `Uncaught ReferenceError: $ is not defined at add:271` and I think this is the problem, then, in this line has this code below generated by `CaptchaMvc.Mvc5`.

**line 271**

```
<div class="text-center">

<script type="text/javascript">
$(function () {$('#0e12b41cddf84cd6a548118316ab8aed').show();}); //line 271

function ______3eec991ccebe425ba220485ba983374e________() { $('#0e12b41cddf84cd6a548118316ab8aed').hide(); $.post("/DefaultCaptcha/Refresh", { t: $('#CaptchaDeText').val() }, function(){$('#0e12b41cddf84cd6a548118316ab8aed').show();}); return false; }</script> 
<br/>
<img id="CaptchaImage" src="/DefaultCaptcha/Generate?t=d230fe1e79a3448f987705cf22a90432"/><input id="CaptchaDeText" name="CaptchaDeText" type="hidden" value="d230fe1e79a3448f987705cf22a90432" /> <br/><a href="#CaptchaImage" id="0e12b41cddf84cd6a548118316ab8aed" onclick="______3eec991ccebe425ba220485ba983374e________()" style="display:none;">Refresh</a><br/>Digite o texto da imagem acima<br/><input autocomplete="off" autocorrect="off" data-val="true" data-val-required="Texto requerido" id="CaptchaInputText" name="CaptchaInputText" type="text" value="" /><br/><span class="field-validation-valid" data-valmsg-for="CaptchaInputText" data-valmsg-replace="true"></span>
            <span class="field-validation-valid" data-valmsg-for="CaptchaInputText" data-valmsg-replace="true"></span>                            
        </div><!--/captcha-->
```

How could I fix it ?

**My Html**

```
@{
var captcha = Html.Captcha("Refresh", "Digite o texto da imagem acima", 5, "Texto requerido", true);
}

<div class="text-center">
   @captcha
   @Html.ValidationMessage(captcha.BuildInfo.InputElementId)                            
</div><!--/captcha-->
```

[image]

Comment: Is jQuery library included in the page before line 271 >

Comment: @Shyju JQuery 2.7.1 ?

Comment: try to reference jquery at the top of the page.
before tags generated by the Captcha components.