# CaptchaMvc.Mvc5 does not refresh partial view

Tags: c#, model-view-controller

I am using the CaptchaMvc.Mvc5 library.
I created a partial view to show the verification code generated by the Captcha, which is activated by @Ajax.ActionLink
When the verification code is wrong, the new code is not generated and generates the following error:
**Failed to load resource: the server responded to a status of 500 (Internal Server Error) http: // localhost: 2755 / DefaultCaptcha / Refresh**

**partial view call**

```c#
@Ajax.ActionLink("PROCESAR PEDIDO", "ValidarCaptcha", "Principal",
                new AjaxOptions {
                  HttpMethod = "GET",
                  UpdateTargetId = "ModalCaptcha"
                },
                new { 
                  @class = "btn btn-flat btn-block",
                  data_toggle = "modal",
                  title = "Validar Captcha",
                  @data_target = "#ModalCaptcha",
                  @id = "btnprocesarpedido" 
                })
```

**Partial view**

```
@using CaptchaMvc.HtmlHelpers


<div class="modal-dialog modal-dialog-centered modal-sm" role="document">
        <div class="modal-content padding10px">
            <div class="modal-header">
                <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal"><span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span></button>
                <h5 class="modal-title font-bold">Title </h5>
            </div>
            <div class="modal-body">
                <div class="row">
                    <div class="col-md-12">
                        @using ( Ajax.BeginForm("ValidarCaptcha", "Principal", new AjaxOptions() { UpdateTargetId = "MensajeAlert", HttpMethod = "Post", InsertionMode = InsertionMode.Replace, OnSuccess = "OnAjaxSuccessCaptcha" }) )
                        {
                            @Html.Captcha("Refrescar", "Ingrese el texto que ve arriba:", 4, "Campo requerido", false)

                            <div class="form-horizontal">
                                <div class="paddingtop15px">
                                    <div id="msjcaptcha"></div>
                                    <input type="submit" value="Enviar" class="btn btn-primary btn-flat" />
                                </div>

                            </div>

                        }

                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
```

**Action Controller**

```
       [HttpPost]
        public ActionResult ValidarCaptcha(string CaptchaInputText)
        {
            int _result = 0;
            string _mensaje = string.Empty;
            string _url = string.Empty;
            try
            {
                if ( this.IsCaptchaValid(CaptchaInputText.ToUpper()) )
                {
                    _result = 1;
                    _url = new UrlHelper(Request.RequestContext).Action("PedidoProcesado", "Principal");
                }
                else
                {
                    _mensaje = "Captcha inválido";
                }

            }
            catch ( Exception ex )
            {
                Utility.RegistrarExcepcion("PrincipalController", "HttpPost()-ValidarCaptcha()", ex.ToString(), Request.Browser.Browser.ToString(), Request.Browser.Version.ToString());
            }

            return Json(new { result = _result, msj = _mensaje, url = _url }, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);

        }
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/u8WHM.png)

Comment: Try decorating the action controller with `[OutputCache(NoStore = true, Duration = 0, VaryByParam = "*")]`

Comment: Thank you asd, But it does not work :(

Comment: Has depurado el codigo para ver en que punto exacto lanza la excepcion?

Comment: Sí, lo he depurado. Cuando se le da clic al botón "Refrescar" la librería llama a este método http://localhost:2755/DefaultCaptcha/Generate?t=bda7a992817a458987ffcf3185d8e091. Pero a nivel de HTML el boton es colocado con display none. Así: `<a href="#CaptchaImage" id="33ce9af86883475ea24483b198606861" onclick="______41b2f124db8b4040b880a3ceb0083bab________()" style="display: none;">Refrescar</a>`

Comment: Si en la capa de servidor no da error, busca como cambiar el valor de display... con none no se ve :/

Comment: El valor de display none se coloca cuando se le da clic al botón refrescar. Estaba viendo este caso pero en mi caso es una vista parcial: [https://stackoverflow.com/q/47397531/2592886]

Comment: Lo siento, no tengo muchos conocimientos de CaptchaMvc.  creo que no puedo ayudarte. Que des con ello ;)